# How to get uib-popover-template to show html fragment

Tags: angularjs, tooltip

From the Angular documentation (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover), I use uib-popover-template to display a html file.  I'm wondering whether there is a way to show just the HTML snippet.

On the main page, there is:

```
<button uib-popover-template="'myTestDoc.html#test1'"  popover-placement="right" class='btn btn-primary'>Help</button>
```

In myTestDoc.html:

```
<div>
  <div id="test1" name="test1">
    some text
  </div>

  <div id="test2" name="test2">
    more text
  </div>
</div>
```

Ideally, it should show the content inside the `<div>` with id="test1".  However, it shows everything in myTestDoc.html.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I believe `uib-popover-template` don't have that feature. What you could do is create a different file just file that snippet, or, since is a small amount of code, pass it as a string (try to make it pretty, though)